# Why is ORACLE throwing ORA-01790?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query with UNION ALL statements.

```
SELECT * FROM HULL_A
    UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM HULL_B;
```

It throws the error

> ORA-01790 "expression must have same datatype as corresponding
>   expression"

However, I checked that, and I think it is not the case. I used the following to check:

```
select db1.data_type, db2.data_type, db1.data_length, db2.data_length, db1.data_precision, db2.data_precision, db1.data_scale, db2.data_scale
from all_tab_columns db1
     inner join all_tab_columns db2
       on (db1.owner = db2.owner
           and db1.column_name = db2.column_name)       
where db1.table_name = 'HULL_A'
  and db2.table_name = 'HULL_B'
  and (
        db1.data_type = db2.data_type
        OR 
        db1.data_length = db2.data_length
      )
```

The result is: 
[image]

I was able to link HULL_A to HULL_C and HULL_D using UNION ALL.

So why is ORACLE throwing the error? What other test could I perform in order to be able to perform the UNION ALL?

I am working on WINDOWS 10 ORACLE 11g

Comment: Oracle does not allow mixing datatypes for a good reasons as it is strictly disallowed by ANSI/ISO SQL standards. see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=fce957718a2bff94845b008eadc219f7)

Comment: @RaymondNijland Do you see a mixing of datatypes in the image? If so please point me to the column.

Comment: *"However, I checked that, and I think it is not the case."* Computers/Software do not lie or give invalid error messages..

Comment: Also see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) for providing better example data and expected results

Comment: The JOIN is not done by COLUMN_NAME but by the position based on the COLUMN_ID, perhaps someone added or deleted columns? Better use qualified names instead of *...

Comment: Why is it throwing an error? Because the data types between the columns don't match. Maybe the order of the columns are different in the two tables (columns are matched by position in an UNION not by name) or those two tables really have different types for the "same" column. Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add the `create table`  statements for both tables as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362)

Comment: @Radagast81 Thank you, using column names instead of * did the trick!

Comment: Use the DUMP command to check the datatypes of the fields in question... take a look at this post here.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56386532/oracle-how-to-map-data-types-to-code-ids-dump-and-dbms-sql-define-column-produ

Comment: Use of "select *" is not a good idea. Prefer to replace the "star" with a list of columns

Answer (score 1):

Columns in both the table must have the same data type and order of the columns must be the same.

You can try the following query to identify the mismatch in columns of both the tables:

```
SELECT
    A.COLUMN_ID COLUMN_HULL_A,
    A.DATA_TYPE DATA_TYPE_HULL_A,
    B.COLUMN_ID COLUMN_HULL_B,
    B.DATA_TYPE DATA_TYPE_HULL_B
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            COLUMN_ID,
            DATA_TYPE
        FROM
            USER_TAB_COLUMNS
        WHERE
            TABLE_NAME = 'HULL_A'
    ) A
FULL OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT
        COLUMN_ID,
        DATA_TYPE
    FROM
        USER_TAB_COLUMNS
    WHERE
        TABLE_NAME = 'HULL_B'
)B ON (A.COLUMN_ID = B.COLUMN_ID AND A.DATA_TYPE = B.DATA_TYPE)
WHERE
    A.COLUMN_ID IS NULL
    OR B.COLUMN_ID IS NULL;
```

Cheers!!

Comment: It is not necessary to have the same column name in both the tables. 
Only the datatype is considered in the union operation. The query will never fail if names of the column in both tables are different at same column ID.