# Finding the age of an event in Oracle

Tags: oracle, date-arithmetic

I have a table of sales with an `ordered` column as a `timestamp` type.

I would like to find the number of days since the last order. I though it should be simple.

I have tried various methods, but I can’t get a meaningful answer:

```sql
select max(ordered) from sales;                         --  2022-05-17 22:47:24.467000
select sysdate-max(ordered) from sales;                 --  Unknown column type: 10
select current_time_stamp-max(ordered) from sales;      --  Unknown column type: 10
```

I want to use the result in a CTE to then add to some other dates, so I thought it should at least result in either an `interval` type or a number of days.

How can I get the age of the above date?

Comment: Cannot replicate your error message [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/69hZvlp2). Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statement for your table; and the `INSERT` statements for some sample data so that we can replicate the issue.

Comment: `VARCHAR2` is type 1, `DATE` is type 12, `CHAR` is type 96 and `TIMESTAMP` is type 180. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56386532/1509264) has a list of type codes and type 10 is not included as one of the standard ones so it looks like you are using a non-standard data-type and that is what is causing your issues. As I commented before, you need to include the `CREATE TABLE` statement to be able to answer this question because the issue is **NOT** the SQL queries you are using but is with the data-type of the column.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 common options:

1. cast timestamp to date and use `sysdate - cast(max(...) as date)` - in this case you'll get a number in days:

```sql
SQL> select sysdate - cast(timestamp'2000-01-01 00:00:00' as date) diff1 from dual;

     DIFF1
----------
8290.97766
```

2. use `systimestamp - max(...)` - in this case you'll get an [Interval Day to Second](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-169DE9FB-36A5-4087-9857-7F03DCF8D3C6.htm):

```sql
SQL> select systimestamp - timestamp'2000-01-01 00:00:00' from dual;

SYSTIMESTAMP-TIMESTAMP'2000-01-0100:00:00'
------------------------------------------
+000008291 00:27:19.105859000
```